# Public-Private Cloud (Hybrid Cloud)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloud

Let's assume that I have a limited budget to make a small in-house private cloud. Now I want to be able to combine this private cloud with one of the public clouds (e.g. Amazon EC2). what options do I have?

More specifically I want to be able to do the following:

1. Use my private cloud primarily but if the request rate or size of datasets increased, transfer part of the load/data to EC2
2. Store my confidential data on the private cloud and move the more general data to EC2. Upon receiving a request, I want to be able to do some computation on the public data and then combine that with some computation on confidential data. But the confidentiality of the data must not be compromised.

I am looking into this for a project and would appreciate any idea/suggestions or related material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a difficult question because the variety and amount of paths you can take in order to do this is great.

Anyway, what you're describing it's an hybrid cloud:

First you have to build your private cloud, there are plenty of options to do this, you have CloudStack, OpenStack, Eucalyptus, Open Nebula, etc. If you choose the open source way (I recommend it) you can see this analysis of the different open source cloud computing solutions:

http://bit.ly/QeGpqK

When you have your own infrastructure managed by your private cloud, you need a third party provider like Amazon for deploy the "public side" of your infrastructure.

And now comes the hard part:

You have tu build your own logic in order to scale your infrastructure to your "public side", and this will be actually the 80% of the work, you have to plan when, what and where you will scale, you have to identify what data you want to store in the public side, etc...

Tools like Rackspace can help you a little bit:

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/hybrid/

Answer (score 1):

@arcade_fire provides an excellent overview of competing private cloud offerings that are OpenSource.  To this list, you could add Microsoft's SCVMM and VMWare's vCloud.  Depending on budget and workload, these proprietary offerings may also be of interest.

After choosing a cloud O/S, consider the following problems:

1. How do you make the public and private elements of the hybrid cloud transparent to your network?
2. How do you control the resulting Hybrid cloud?

The first issue is addressed by using what is referred to as VPC (virtual private cloud).  This term was introduced by AWS to describe a public cloud deployment that sits on a private network.  These machines are joined to your private cloud via a VPN.  One end of the VPN is in the cloud, and the other in your data center.  A google of "aws vpc architecture" will net you a good explanation.  I liked [EC2 to VPC: A transition worth doing](http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/12288961849/ec2-to-vpc-transition-worth-doing)

The second issue involves you choosing admin tools to manage your work load that support the API used to communicate to each of your public and private accounts.  The architype example is [RightScale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RightScale), which supports a number of APIs, but there are others.  @arcade_fire provides a link to Rackspace.  Alternatively, you can find consultancies that can tailor a tool depending on the intended workload e.g. [ShapeBlue](http://www.shapeblue.com/iaas-cloud-design-and-build/) (CloudStack ecosystem).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Using a VPN seems a logical answer if there was no specific policy to be enforced. What I want to do is to make sure that none of the confidential data on my private cloud goes to public space. It is OK if the data from public cloud gets into private but not reversely. More general, I want to be able to enforce a specific policy and modify it without going through much manual modification. Is there any way to combine them with a specific policy? thanks

Comment: How do you intend to store your data? Virtual-machine centric would put it in VMs whose volumes.  Volumes are challenging to transfer from one cloud to another.  Storage service-centric raises the possibility that the data gets transferred.  E.g. with Dropbox's functionality comes the problem that your data leaves premises.  One solution is to leave the data in an object store like Swift (available with OpenStack and CloudStack) or a distributed file system (like what's available with Hadoop).  Add only private cloud hosts as nodes to this store, and your data will not leave your premises.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to have your own hybrid cloud you have to have you own code that look after the scaleUP and other provision task .
for private cloud you can go for eucalyptus or OpenQRM . if you are comfortable with Linux you can use Open source KVM that comes bundled with Linux OS hosted on apache server , you can call its exposed methods from your java or PHP code and carry out the provision and de-provision task . or otherwise you can simply use the management console provided by KVM.
citrix -Xen is also one of the option.
Now for public cloud EC2 is an option other than that you can use various other Iaas.
for high availability you can Open-source apache HAProxy that take care of your load balancing.
as you are dealing with some data you have the options to go for BIG data providers that includes , mapreduse ,Terradata , IBM-netzza ,cloudere for graph and other analysis you can use splunk and as apache hadoop with pig and hive is always an option .

the scaleUP code you have to write along with the integration of private and public cloud. Amazon exposes its web service you can leverage it ....

Answer (score 0):

there are professional vendors who offer this combined service of both a private (primarily) and a public cloud. it's called a hybrid cloud, you build your own private one to serve your project, and you've got some drawn elements from public clouds to serve you even better, in cases of increased data base while your own cloud is limited. i personally like stratoscale, their symphony product is good and serves all of a customer's needs (from my experience), but obviously you've got many out there (they work with openstack as well.)

Answer (score -1):

The thing you're describing is undoubtedly a Hybrid cloud deployment model. Out of my experience with our team I can recommend you go ahead give a third party tool a chance. Third party services nowadays allow you to have all the relevant freedom of action within the cloud environment, which basically means you have the complete control over your cloud resources. Those services let you manage your on-premise private cloud along with using AWS as an-on premise, which is a very advanced function. You might want to check it out as well as for the costs, most of these tools offer a free trial.